# regex url to image in php

Tags: php, regex, security, validation, url

I am making a profile page where users can set an url to their profile image. How do I check this with regex for example?

Comment: What exactly are you intending to "check"? What are the criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cURL for the mime. For the URL validation I use the following, but there are loads out there. You can use `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` but it can contain bugs; http://bugs.php.net/51192.

```
$url='image.png';

if( preg_match("#((http|https|ftp)://(\S*?\.\S*?))(\s|\;|\)|\]|\[|\{|\}|,|\"|'|:|\<|$|\.\s)#ie", $url) ){

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://yoursite.com');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $mime = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
    curl_close($ch);

    print $mime;

}
```

Comment: the preg_match seems to block valid urls like "http://www.itavisen.no/gfx/speedometerNy.png"

Comment: I've updated it, as there were some other errors with it. I generally prefer that URLs are prefixed with HTTP. Personal preference :) but I use this for URLs that will be placed into the href of the HTML base tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Any file can be served at any address. You'd need to check the Content-Type returned by the URL, and probably the format of the image too.

Comment: Well, you might at least test that it's a valid URL.

Comment: If that's the real question then it's a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this?

[best way to determine if a URL is an image in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676949/best-way-to-determine-if-a-url-is-an-image-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`.

Look at : [parsing url - php, check if scheme exists, validate url regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283448/parsing-url-php-check-if-scheme-exists-validate-url-regex)

Answer (score 0):

First test that is a valid url with `filter_var()`

```
$url = filter_var($variable, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED);
```

Then you'll need to download the resource, and test locally if it's an image.